# convert multiple variable output to a table in bash

Tags: bash

I have 3 variables, `$commonName`, `$expiryDate` and `$DaysRemInUnixEpoch`. Each variable has 3 lines as below output. I want to display output of all 3 variables in to 3 different columns. I tried looking for solution using printf but no luck. Can anyone please advise if they have done this in the past using printf and how? Any help will be much appreciated.

Below are 3 variables output together in one column. I want to split in to 3 columns having 3 rows in each column.

```
bash-4.1$ echo -e  "$commonName\n$expiryDate\n$daysRemInUnixEpoch" 
mycertificate_mycert.mycomp.net
PSIN0P551
ROOTROOTCA
Feb 6 2022 11:57:32 GMT
Jan 9 2023 18:51:25 GMT
Mar 12 2035 18:24:54 GMT
682
1020
5465
bash-4.1$
```

desired output I am looking for is something like below

`mycertificate_mycert.mycomp.net    Feb 6 2022 11:57:32 GMT  682
PSIN0P551                           Jan 9 2023 18:51:25 GMT  1020
ROOTROOTCA                          Mar 12 2035 18:24:54 GMT 5465`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash (Process Substitution), paste and column:

```
paste -d ';' <(echo "$commonName") <(echo "$expiryDate") <(echo "$daysRemInUnixEpoch") | column -s ';' -t
```

Output:

```
mycertificate_mycert.mycomp.net  Feb 6 2022 11:57:32 GMT   682
PSIN0P551                        Jan 9 2023 18:51:25 GMT   1020
ROOTROOTCA                       Mar 12 2035 18:24:54 GMT  5465
```

I assume that your variables do not contain `;`.

---

see: `man paste` and `man column`

Comment: Hi @Cyrus. paste -d does work exactly the way I want. I wasn't aware of such command. I shall look at more at `man paste` and `man column`. Thanks very much for your help